# What is the cost of elementary operations in C#?

Tags: c#

When I implement an algorithm, I try to use operations that cost as little as possible.

I'd like to know if the basic operations in C# are ordered (in terms of speed or cost) like this:

- comparisons
- (u)int add, subtract, bitops, shift
- floating point add, sub (separate unit!)
- indexed array access (caveat: cache effects)
- (u)int32 mul
- FP mul
- FP division, remainder
- (u)int division, remainder

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx

Comment: All of this is quite irrelevant for the purposes of optimization. Raw comparison of integers may be a lot cheaper than raw division of FP numbers, but if FP numbers are in the CPU cache and integers are not, the division will take a lot less time than comparison (what's faster, dividing two numbers that you already have, or comparing two numbers that you must drive across the city to get?)

Comment: Your question implies that you already know which CPU operations are cheaper, even when you're using a high-level language other than C#. If that is true, then all those things that you already know apply when you are using C# as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Branko Dimitrijevic already pointed out, C# is not executed, it's compiled to IL. That IL is also not executed, it's compiled to machine code. So I have no choice but to reinterpret your question as *"which low-level operations are cheaper on my CPU?"*. Since there are many architectures to speak of and you aren't being specific about which one you're interested in, I'm going to assume x86, since it's the most popular on desktop systems.

The information you're asking about can be found in the [Intel Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html), Appendix C. There, latencies and throughputs for various instructions are listed. Latency is the number of cycles it takes for an instruction to have its results ready for use by a subsequent instruction. Throughput is the number of cycles an instruction stalls its execution unit. Some examples:

- `cmp`, `add`, `sub`, `and`, `or` and `xor` have a latency of 1 and a throughput of 0.25.
- `ror` and `rol` have a latency of 1 to 2 and a throughput of 0.5 to 1.5 depending on where the data are.
- `imul` has a latency of 3 and a throughput of 1 when reading 64-bit registers, but a latency of 4 to 5 and a throughput of 1 when reading 32-bit registers.
- `idiv` has a variable latency and throughput depending on the calculation itself.

So, although I haven't looked up *all* the operations you asked, your proposed list (in ascending order of cost) seems at least reasonable.

---

That's all assuming the question is about the cost of basic operations and nothing more. But if you want to actually micro-optimize a real program, things are quite different.

Notice that, in the same manual and before the timings tables come in, there are *over 600 pages* that describe a plethora of factors that play a significant role in the performance of a program that runs on that architecture. These include the out-of-order execution engine, cache levels, pipelines, branch prediction, which unit runs which instruction, and so on.

If you don't feel like you can attain working knowledge of all these issues, I don't think that there is much point in attempting to micro-optimize at that level. You'll be doing it blindly.

Comment: Thanks, for the great answer!

Answer (score 5):

No "C# operation" is ever executed - it is compiled (into MSIL and then JITted) into machine code, which is dependent on the target architecture. So even if one operation is faster than the other on one architecture, the opposite may be true on another.

What you are asking is incredibly low level anyway. The choice of data structures and algorithms will have orders-of-magnitude more impact, and even when you nail that down, the [memory latencies](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832) are likely to dominate over individual operations.